# How do I format the results of a JSONArray

Tags: java, json, rest, simplejson

So I am trying to use the API here: https://clinicaltables.nlm.nih.gov/apidoc/icd10cm/v3/doc.html#output

This is my code so far:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.json.simple.*;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class DiagnosesAPIHelper 
{
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL ("https://clinicaltables.nlm.nih.gov/api/icd10cm/v3/search?sf=code,name&terms=tuberc");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.connect();

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            
            if(responseCode != 200)
            {
                throw new Exception("HTTP Response code: " + responseCode);
            }
            else
            {

                String inline = "";
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());

                //Write all the JSON data into a string using a scanner
                while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                    inline += scanner.nextLine();
                }

                //Close the scanner
                scanner.close();
                
                //Using the JSON simple library parse the string into a json object
                JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
                JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) parse.parse(inline);

                System.out.println(jsonArray.get(3).toString());
                
                
            }} catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    
    }

}
```

**And here are the outputs that I am getting:**

```
[["A15.0","Tuberculosis of lung"],["A15.4","Tuberculosis of intrathoracic lymph nodes"],["A15.5","Tuberculosis of larynx, trachea and bronchus"],["A15.6","Tuberculous pleurisy"],["A15.7","Primary respiratory tuberculosis"],["A15.8","Other respiratory tuberculosis"],["A15.9","Respiratory tuberculosis unspecified"]]
```

How would I extract the ICD code, and the diagnoses description?

So with what I get [["A15.0","Tuberculosis of lung"]

How would I make 2 strings out of it one for the A15.0 part, and another for the Tuberculosis of lung part.

I can tokenize it, but that would be quite a bit of work. There has to be an easier way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did my answer help you? or do you want me to add something to my answer? otherwise, feel free to accept my answer if you like.

Answer (score 0):

In order to iterate on the elements of a JSON array, you have to cast the returned general object to `JSONArray`.

In your example `jsonArray.get(3)` returns a general object because in a JSON you can have different types of objects such as number, string and array.

However, you know that `jsonArray.get(3)` returns an array so if you cast you can handle the result like an array or a list.

This is an example that you can put after `System.out.println(jsonArray.get(3).toString());`

```java
JSONArray elements = (JSONArray) jsonArray.get(3);
for (Object element : elements) {
    JSONArray elementJSONArray = (JSONArray) element;
    System.out.println("code: " + elementJSONArray.get(0));
    System.out.println("description: " + elementJSONArray.get(1));
}
```

Output

```sh
code: A15.0
description: Tuberculosis of lung
code: A15.4
description: Tuberculosis of intrathoracic lymph nodes
code: A15.5
description: Tuberculosis of larynx, trachea and bronchus
code: A15.6
description: Tuberculous pleurisy
code: A15.7
description: Primary respiratory tuberculosis
code: A15.8
description: Other respiratory tuberculosis
code: A15.9
description: Respiratory tuberculosis unspecified
```